# How to make text go to the left when user inputs too many characters?

Tags: java, graphics, user-input, textview, calculator, android

I have built a calculator using java code, but when the user inputs too many characters, the characters at the right most side disappear and user cannot see them.

I have put this code in `mainactivity.xml`

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

For example if you enter `1234123412341234567`, you will be unable to see the character after five (at right).

How do I programmatically make the the characters on the left move to accommodate new characters?

Comment: i m not very knowledgable in andorid, but i would make either the whole display to text size ratio smaller or check the user input value and  change the ratio if a certain treshhold is crossed.

Comment: Not an android expert, but I’d look at using a non editable text field and adjust the cursor position if possible

Answer (score 0):

You must set the Edittext gravity to the Right,like below:

```
android:gravity="right"
```